# Error executing devicectl: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally: ERROR: Command timeout of 5.0 seconds exceeded

Tags: android, ios, flutter, build

The other day I installed vscode, android studio and xcode to their latest versions. When I try to open the application I developed in Flutter on Android and iOS devices, it gives the following warning. What is the reason ? (Device : Mac M1 Air)

> Error executing devicectl: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
> ERROR: Command timeout of 5.0 seconds exceeded. Assuming command got stuck and aborting.
> Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun devicectl list devices --timeout 5 --json-output /var/folders/wl/b1tblj8j3fl493jjlv2spx0c0000gn/T/flutter_tools.4rXbnw/core_devices.DgOGjO/core_device_list.json
> Error executing devicectl: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
> ERROR: Command timeout of 5.0 seconds exceeded. Assuming command got stuck and aborting.
> Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun devicectl list devices --timeout 5 --json-output /var/folders/wl/b1tblj8j3fl493jjlv2spx0c0000gn/T/flutter_tools.4rXbnw/core_devices.qSwMts/core_device_list.json
> Error executing devicectl: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
> ERROR: Command timeout of 5.0 seconds exceeded. Assuming command got stuck and aborting.
> Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun devicectl list devices --timeout 5 --json-output /var/folders/wl/b1tblj8j3fl493jjlv2spx0c0000gn/T/flutter_tools.4rXbnw/core_devices.M9Q84K/core_device_list.json

Comment: I am facing the same error. If it helps, the new simulator - iOS 17 on iPhone 15 Pro Max

Comment: Yes, I get the same error in all emulators. (also on Android)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Re)opening XCode and installing the additional components (as requested by XCode) did the trick for me.